# How to get float left to not center the div instead in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

In IE10 I have two `div` tags that I need to get side-by-side. On Mac Chrome, Safari and Firefox, everything works like intended. In Internet Explorer 10 on windows for example, the `divs` are not floating as intended.

I'm also using some twitter bootstrap classes for different device layouts if that makes any difference.

```
<div class="hidden-xs" style="width: 1000px;">
    <div style="width: 470px; float: left;">a</div>
    <div style="width: 530px; float: right;">b</div> 
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

In **Internet Explorer 10** it looks like this:

[image: In IE broken]

In **Chrome** it looks like this (as intended):

[image: Chrome as intended]

In **Internet Explorer 10** when I uncheck the `box-sizing` property, the `float` starts to work but It messes up other elements on the site.
[image: IE without box-sizing]

My questions:

**1. Why is IE doing this when in other browsers (on Mac) it seems to work.**

**2. How to simply fix it?** I've tried changing the `widths` of the `divs` and replaced `float left` with `right`. I also removed the `clear: both` `div` to see any difference.

**3. How does removing the box-sizing fix the problem?**

Comment: Think you need to clear hidden-xs by something like this. http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: Why not just use a list `<ul>` with `display:inline`?

Comment: Were you tried to set margin,padding and border to 0 in those divs?

Comment: You must have some other stuff in your code.  That same code you gave, putting into jsfiddle and running on IE10, worked like a charm.

Comment: Setting clear: both; to hidden-xs made it work. I wonder why..
Tried with ul before and didn't give desired layout. I also tried setting margin, padding and border to 0. That didn't work. And that other stuff is probably twitter bootstrap.

Comment: why are you even using clear? Just set parent `div` with `overflow:auto` to avoid having no background (or you can do `* { overflow:auto; }` )

Comment: I tried `overflow:auto` right now. It will make the two `divs` go side by side, but they both stay far too right. The first `div` should float to left but does not with `overlfow:auto`. Setting `clear:both` on parent does the trick tho.

Comment: You must have some funky code in there... http://jsfiddle.net/XV65H/

Answer (score 2):

just try this

```
    <div class="hidden-xs" style="width: 1000px; float:left;">
      <div style="width: 470px; float: left;">a</div>
      <div style="width: 530px; float: left;">b</div> 
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your 530px div make it float: left instead of right and add position: relative to both the 530 and 470 div's.